# Add checked items to array and remove when unchecked

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Uitableview which has Accessory type set as "CheckMark" if the cell is selected (Checked) I want to add the contents of the cell to an array and if it is unchecked I want to remove the same from the array.

I have added this code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [listingSet indexPathForSelectedRow];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
} 
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"ID"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"++++++IDSSS %@",ID);
    NSString *titlename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"UserFileName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"fileExtension"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];                                                                                                            
    [Selectedfiles addObject:ID];
    [Selectedfiles retain];
    NSLog(@"++++++Titlesss %@",Selectedfiles);
    [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [listingSet indexPathForSelectedRow];

ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"ID"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

     // Remove id 
     [Selectedfiles removeObject:ID];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
} 
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    // Add id 
     [Selectedfiles addObject:ID];

    NSLog(@"++++++IDSSS %@",ID);
    NSString *titlename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"UserFileName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"fileExtension"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];                                                                                                            


    NSLog(@"++++++Titlesss %@",Selectedfiles);
    [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
  }
}
```